How can i stream incoming pcm16 data in flutter/ iOS?
This is my flutter code for the incoming data, what I get is a uint8list data stream that kinda looks like this (if transcribed)
Hello
Hello how
Hello how are
Hello how are you?
client.on(RealtimeEventType.conversationUpdated, (e) async {
      final event = e as RealtimeEventConversationUpdated;
      final item = event.result.item;

      if (item?.formatted?.audio != null && item!.formatted!.audio.isNotEmpty) {
        try {
           await _trickleAudioStream?.playAudioStream(item.formatted!.audio, isFirstChunk);
          if (isFirstChunk) {
            isFirstChunk = false;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print("EXCEPTION: $e");
        }
      }
    });

and this is my native code (for the plugin I'm writing)
import Flutter
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

struct CircularBuffer<Element> {
    private var array: [Element?]
    private var readIndex = 0
    private var writeIndex = 0
    private(set) var count = 0
    private let capacity: Int
    
    
    init(capacity: Int) {
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.array = Array(repeating: nil, count: capacity)
        
    }
    
    mutating func write(_ element: Element) {
        array[writeIndex % capacity] = element
        writeIndex += 1
        if count < capacity {
            count += 1
        } else {
            readIndex += 1 // Overwrite oldest if buffer is full
        }
    }
    
    mutating func read() -> Element? {
        guard count > 0 else { return nil }
        let element = array[readIndex % capacity]
        array[readIndex % capacity] = nil
        readIndex += 1
        count -= 1
        return element
    }
}



public class TrickleAudioStreamPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
    ...
    
    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "trickle_audio_stream", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = TrickleAudioStreamPlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }
    
    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        if call.method == "playAudioStream" {
            guard let args = call.arguments as? [String: Any],
                  let pcmData = args["data"] as? FlutterStandardTypedData,
                  let isFirst = args["isFirst"] as? Bool else {
                result(FlutterError(code: "INVALID_ARGUMENTS", message: "Invalid arguments", details: nil))
                return
            }
            
            let data = pcmData.data
            
            let timestamp = playAudioStream(convertPCM16ToFloat32(data), isFirst: isFirst)
            result(timestamp)
        } else if call.method == "stopAudioStream" {
            stopAudioStream()
        } else {
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
    }
    
    func stopAudioStream() {
        playerNode.stop()
        isPlaying = false
    }
    
    func playAudioStream(_ floatPCMData: Data, isFirst: Bool) -> Double {
            if isFirst {
                resetBuffers()
                stopAudioStream()
                processedDataLength = 0
                
                do {
                    try startAudioEngine()
                    playerNode.play()
                    isPlaying = true
                } catch {
                    print("Error starting audio engine: \(error)")
                    return timeNow()
                }
            }
            
            guard floatPCMData.count > processedDataLength else {
                return timeNow()
            }
            
            let newData = floatPCMData.subdata(in: processedDataLength..<floatPCMData.count)
            processedDataLength = floatPCMData.count
            
            guard let buffer = createPCMBuffer(from: newData) else {
                print("Failed to create PCM buffer")
                return timeNow()
            }
            
            buffers.append(buffer)
            currentSegmentDuration += Double(buffer.frameLength) / format.sampleRate

            playerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer) {
                self.currentPlaybackPosition += Double(buffer.frameLength) / self.format.sampleRate
                if let nextBuffer = self.buffers.first {
                    self.buffers.removeFirst()
                    self.playerNode.scheduleBuffer(nextBuffer) {
                        // Schedule next on completion
                    }
                }
            }

            if isFirst {
                playerNode.play()
                isPlaying = true
            }
            
            return timeNow()
        }
    
    
    
    func startAudioEngine() throws {
        if !audioEngine.isRunning {
            try audioEngine.start()
        }
    }
    
    private func createPCMBuffer(from floatPCMData: Data) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
        let frameCount = floatPCMData.count / MemoryLayout<Float>.size
        guard let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(frameCount)) else {
            return nil
        }
        buffer.frameLength = buffer.frameCapacity
        
        floatPCMData.withUnsafeBytes { floatBytes in
            let floatBufferPointer = floatBytes.bindMemory(to: Float.self).baseAddress!
            buffer.floatChannelData?.pointee.update(from: floatBufferPointer, count: frameCount)
        }
        return buffer
    }
    
    func resetBuffers() {
        buffers.removeAll()
        currentSegmentDuration = 0
        currentPlaybackPosition = 0
        playerNode.reset()
    }
    
    private func timeNow() -> Double {
        return Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    }
    
    
    private func convertPCM16ToFloat32(_ pcm16Data: Data) -> Data {
        var floatData = Data(capacity: pcm16Data.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.size / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
        pcm16Data.withUnsafeBytes { (int16Pointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
            let int16Buffer = int16Pointer.bindMemory(to: Int16.self)
            for sample in int16Buffer {
                let floatSample = Float(sample) / Float(Int16.max)
                floatData.append(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: floatSample) { Data($0) })
            }
        }
        return floatData
    }
}


But sometimes it starts playing older audio again or small parts of it.
I expect the data to be streamed seamlessly and play the audio without repeating previous chunks of data.
